# CakePHP Model X has Category A or B where A and B each have tables linked back to Model X

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model

Another way of putting it is that I want to alter the fields of `Fruit` based on whether it belongs to `Category[X or Y or Z]`

I'm having a hard time articulating just what I need to do, hence needing to ask because I haven't quite figured out how to look for an answer.

Anyway, what I want to do is have a model like `Fruit`, which has several fields of information including a `category`.  The thing is I need `fruit_category_A` to have different fields from `fruit_category_B` and I need to be able to access the contents those fields through the model `Fruit`.

I'm sure there are several ways of achieving this sort of functionality but I just can't figure out what route to take.  I've thought of maybe having `Fruit` related to `FruitType` which would be related to `FruitTypeA` and `FruitTypeB` which each in turn would be related back to `Fruit` but then I'm not sure how to make the associations and that sort of structure seems clunky.

BTW I'm using MySQL as DB and CakePHP 2.2.1

Comment: what do you mean by ' I need `fruit_category_A` to have different fields from `fruit_category_B`'? Can you expand this part a bit?

Comment: As in the fruits under `fruit_category_A` might have fields for `X`, `Y` and `Z` while fruits under `fruit_category_B` would have fields for `U`, `V`, `W`.  `fruit` would have fields `A`, `B` and `C` and I would want to be able to append to each fruit the fields of its respective category.  So that `fruit` that is `fruit_category_a` the fields altogether would be `A B C X Y Z`.